# How to plot a marker away from another marker by 100 metres in Mapbox Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to plot a marker using Leaflet and then another marker away from the the first one by 100 metres. Plotting a marker is easy:

```
var marker = L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(map);
```

But now how do I plot another marker away from this one by a 100 metres?
Is there a way to convert metres to long and lat and then plotting it?
Or is there a better way already that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/duywyszh/1/) to show an example. It's based on these answers:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/how-to-generate-random-locations-nearby-my-location

```
var r = 100/111300 // = 100 meters
  , y0 = original_lat
  , x0 = original_lng
  , u = Math.random()
  , v = Math.random()
  , w = r * Math.sqrt(u)
  , t = 2 * Math.PI * v
  , x = w * Math.cos(t)
  , y1 = w * Math.sin(t)
  , x1 = x / Math.cos(y0)

newY = y0 + y1
newX = x0 + x1
```